# STcontains() query running slow even with Spatial Index

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, geospatial, spatial

I have one table called 'Region' which has got 2000 records. In the region table I have 1 geometry column called points. Now I have another table called Bus_Route with geometry column called 'geometry' with 10 million records.  Now I want the points which lie in that region. I am using the following query to see weather my point lies in that region or not by using STcontains. But this query is taking long time (around 3 days). I have created Spatial index on my Bus_Route table which has got 10 million records but that didn't help as well.

```
         Select
              Region.BlockID,
              Bus_Route.geometry
              from 
              Bus_Route,                         
              Region
           where 

              Region.points.STContains(Bus_Route.geometry) = 1
```

Please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of observations:

1. Because your bus probably doesn't run through Flatland, use
   geography instead of geometry.
2. If you're going to do a cross join
   (which, your query as stated is doing), be explicit about it by
   doing something like:

   Select
      Region.BlockID,
      Bus_Route.geometry
   from Bus_Route
   cross join Region
3. Have you looked at using STIntersects instead of STContains? If I'm interpreting your problem correctly, you're looking for regions that a given route passes through, which means that the intersection between the two geo instances would be non-empty. The query you've written will show routes that are fully enclosed within a region.

Comment: Hi Ben,

Thanks for youe reply.

I have converted my geometry to geography now ths issue is I have 4000 lat/long points which make a region and I want to check 1 point lat/long exist in that region(4000 points) or not.

How can I use STContains geography on that?

DECLARE @g geography;
DECLARE @h geography;
SET @g = 4000 points having lat/long which are stored in DB
SET @h = geography (The lat/long point i want to check)

Please help!

Comment: When you say that you have 4000 points that make a region, are those points the endpoints of line segments that define the boundary of the region? I'm not fishing for points here, but that is an interesting question in and of itself (i.e. you should make a separate question for that). My first guess is that you're going to have to get a textual representation of the region from the points and then use a static geography method to parse that back into a geography instance. That seems roundabout to me, though; I'll do some digging.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Ben. I will explain in more detail. I have lat/long of a region (Outline of the lat/longs which makes a region) in geography form. Now I have 1 point lat/long and I want to identify if that point lies inside my region. How will I do that? So here 4000 points makes outline of a region and 1 point is to check if that exist in that region or not. How will I check that?  THanks for your answers Ben!

Comment: Yes. You and I are saying the same thing with respect to your problem. What I'm asking you to do is log another question. While it's related to your business problem, it's really another technical problem, with interesting answers that others might find useful.

Comment: Oh... and let me know where it is; I have something that just might work. ;)

Comment: Hi ben..This is the link   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13484636/stcontains-on-geography-column