# STContains on Geography column

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2, spatial

I have a bus point in Lat/long (geography). I want to check where my bus point (lat/long) lies in a region. My region is a set of lat/long points. I have lat/long of a region (Outline of the lat/longs which makes a region) in geography form. Now I have one point lat/long and I want to identify if that point lies inside my region. How can I do that? 4000 points make an outline of a region and one point is to check if that exist in that region or not. How will I check that?

I think I can use `STContains` or `STintersect` but I don't know the exact syntax.

```
SELECT
    Region.BlockID, Bus_Route.geography
FROM
    Bus_Route, Region
WHERE
    Region.points.STContains(Bus_Route.geography) = 1
```

Comment: Are your region points numbered? Is your region always convex?

Comment: Hi there, My region is in lat/long (single points outline of a region) and my bus route is also in lat/long (1 record of lat/long per row). Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used the code that I wrote for you ([*Storing 'Point' column from ShapeFile*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12809201/storing-point-column-from-shapefile/12809687#12809687)) as a starting point to get a table of points. From there:

```
select geography::STPolyFromText(
'POLYGON((' + 
    stuff((
        select ',' + cast(g.STPointN(t.i).Long as varchar(10)) + ' ' + cast(g.STPointN(t.i).Lat as varchar(10))
        from [a]
        cross join tally as [t]
        where t.i <= g.STNumPoints()
        order by i
        for xml path('')

    ), 1, 1, '') + '))'
    , 4326)
```

This code assumes a couple of things. First: that your points are ordered as you would go around the boundary of the region. This matters. Think about a connect-the-dots puzzle. In order to get the right picture, you have to do them in the right order. Secondly, related to the first, they have to be in the correct orientation. Polygons follow the left-hand rule. That is, if you were walking the points in order, you're defining the region that is at your left side. So, if you specify the points in reverse order, you get everything but your region! You'll know this right away since before SQL 2012, you're limited to having regions that are fully contained in a hemisphere.

But now I have to ask: given the question that you asked before (that I linked to above), are you receiving shapefiles with polygons in them? If so, store that and save yourself the headache of reconstructing it.

Comment: Hi Ben .. Thanks again for your reply. I will explain in bit more detail. I am getting Shapefile which contains 1 lat/long per record for a corresponding Bus. So if the Bus has travel from New York to Chicago, my shapefile will have have 1 million records (one lat/long recorded every second). So now I load that 1 million files on my SQL Server(Remember 1 have single lat/long for the bus route). Now I have geometry column for a region from which I am extracting each points using STNumPoints() . By this i get the outline of the region in points format.

Comment: If I'm reading your question above correctly, you should do something like select r.STContains(p) from region cross join points. If you have the region stored as a polygon and the points stored as, well, points, this should give you a true/false indicator for each point saying whether it's in the region or not.